# jQuery ajax return undefined instead of promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

1.8.2

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "/someurl/",
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function ( data ) {
    if( console && console.log ) {
      console.log("Sample of data: ", data);
    }
  });
```

causes error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'done' of undefined", but request sends and server response comes to me with data!
If I wrote

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "/someurl/",
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) { console.log(data); }
  });
```

That's ok and console.log fires!

Comment: The last version w/o deferred was 1.4. In this version only the [XMLHttpRequest object has been returned](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.4.1&fn=jQuery.ajax) - Are you sure about version 1.8.2? Any older version which is included after 1.8?

Comment: jQuery.fn.jquery returns me "1.8.2"

Comment: Then I have to give up for now... :\

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that your error probably comes from the way your using the response data, because your snippet is correct.

Why don't you run a fail method and test for errors there?

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/someurl/",
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json'
  }).fail(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Alternatively, check your Network Tab for xhr response preview?